# ERROR installing npm install --save pdfmake

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, datatable

I am doing a project with `vue` and `laravel 5.6`, I need to install `npm install --save pdfmake` `npm install --save datatables.net-bs4` `npm install --save datatables.net-buttons-bs4`

but I get an error. BEFORE THE ERROR I FIGURE THIS WARNING, I DON'T KNOW IF THERE WILL BE SOMETHING TO SEE

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'got@5.7.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.10.0 <7' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

[image]

Comment: One of the packages you're trying to install is using an older version of `got`, which requires an nom version less than 7, if I'm reading it right.

Comment: Is issue closed ?